# ng2-bootstrap Uncaught ReferenceError when adding the script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to add ng2-bootstrap to my project. I try adding the script, adding the cdn. But I always get the same error:

ng2-bootstrap.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined ng2-bootstrap.js:1

I saw that other people is having the same error, but no answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you need to have system.js in your project: